# CSS overflow mac with new chrome

Tags: html, css, macos, google-chrome, overflow

Today I started to notice that I always see the scrollers on my mac (chrome 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) ) This is the new chrome version. 
here is a example of this:

```css
.FixedHeightContainer {
  float: right;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #f00;
}

.Content {
  height: 224px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="FixedHeightContainer">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div class="Content">
    blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
    blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
    ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah
    blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
    ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah... ..blah blah blah...
  </div>
</div>
```

previous versions do not do this. can anyone confirm or suggest a solution to this problem.

So.. my question is : How I make it **only** show when needed like before ?

Comment: Looks like you already gave `overflow: auto;` which does it. Can you show a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: Sure , now: [backGround](http://imgur.com/TzhlWvB) , before: they were hiden until I scroll with the mouse

Comment: I can see that myself. What is the problem now? How it should come, and how it comes?

Comment: you can see my demo sir hope help you @TalYahav

Comment: In chrome ver 47.0.2526.111 is working like I want ^^* but the new ver  48.0.2564.97  make it like this .. Is there a why to make ver 48.0.2564.97 behave like before?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
.FixedHeightContainer {
  float: right;
  height: 350px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #f00;
}

.Content {
  height: 224px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/a9u820kd/)

**or**

```
.FixedHeightContainer {
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #f00;
}

.Content {
  height: 224px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[**DEMO UPDATED**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/a9u820kd/1/)

Add `height:auto;`